# How to run samba server in testContainers based on existing docker-compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, testing, samba, testcontainers

I have following **docker-compose** file for local development:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  mynetwork:

services:
  samba:
    image: instantlinux/samba-dc:latest
    container_name: samba-dc
    cap_add:
      - CAP_SYS_ADMIN
    hostname: my.org
    environment:
      DOMAIN_ACTION: provision
      REALM: my.org
    volumes:
      - etc:/etc/samba
      - lib:/var/lib/samba
    ports:
      - "53:53"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "88:88"
      - "88:88/udp"
      - "389:389"
    secrets:
      - samba-admin-password

volumes:
  etc:
  lib:

secrets:
  samba-admin-password:
    file: secrets.yaml
```

Now I try to implement integration tests using testContainers with the same dependencies as mentioned above:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class MyTestContainersTestBase {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory())
        val secretPathOnHost = "C:\\work\\myProject\\docker\\secrets.yaml"
        val secretsFile = File(secretPathOnHost)

        val secretsData: Map<String, Any> = mapper.readValue(secretsFile, object : TypeReference<Map<String, Any>>() {})

        // Extract the secret from the parsed data
        val adminPassword = (secretsData["data"] as Map<*, *>?)!!["ADMIN_PASSWORD_SECRET"] as String?

        val secretPathInContainer = "/run/secrets/samba-admin-password";
        // Create and start the container
        val ldapContainer = GenericContainer("instantlinux/samba-dc:latest")
            .withEnv("DOMAIN_ACTION", "provision")
            .withEnv("REALM", "my.company")
            .withEnv("ADMIN_PASSWORD_SECRET", adminPassword) // Set the extracted secret as an environment variable
            .withEnv("LOG_LEVEL", "0")
            .withEnv("ALLOW_DNS_UPDATES", "secure")
            .withEnv("BIND_INTERFACES_ONLY", "yes ")
            .withEnv("DOMAIN_ACTION", "provision")
            .withEnv("DOMAIN_LOGONS", "yes")
            .withEnv("DOMAIN_MASTER", "no")
            .withEnv("INTERFACES", "lo eth0")
            .withEnv("NETBIOS_NAME", "")
            .withEnv("SERVER_STRING", "Samba Domain Controller")
            .withEnv("TZ", "UTC")
            .withEnv("WINBIND_USE_DEFAULT_DOMAIN", "yes")
            .withEnv("WORKGROUP", "AD")

            .withExposedPorts(53, 88, 389)
            .withFileSystemBind(secretPathOnHost, secretPathInContainer, BindMode.READ_ONLY)
        ldapContainer.start()

        print("qwerty")

        Thread.sleep(100000000)
    }
}
```

### [image]

[image]
As a result I see that test starts, testContainer starts, samba server tried to starts but fails with error in log:

```
2023-09-18 18:47:50 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:50,489 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2108: Looking up IPv4 addresses
2023-09-18 18:47:50 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:50,490 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2125: Looking up IPv6 addresses
2023-09-18 18:47:50 WARNING 2023-09-18 15:47:50,490 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2132: No IPv6 address will be assigned
2023-09-18 18:47:51 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:51,384 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2274: Setting up share.ldb
2023-09-18 18:47:51 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:51,483 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2278: Setting up secrets.ldb
2023-09-18 18:47:51 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:51,621 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2283: Setting up the registry
2023-09-18 18:47:51 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:51,965 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2286: Setting up the privileges database
2023-09-18 18:47:52 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:52,103 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2289: Setting up idmap db
2023-09-18 18:47:52 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:52,199 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2296: Setting up SAM db
2023-09-18 18:47:52 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:52,218 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #880: Setting up sam.ldb partitions and settings
2023-09-18 18:47:52 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:52,220 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #892: Setting up sam.ldb rootDSE
2023-09-18 18:47:52 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:52,233 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1305: Pre-loading the Samba 4 and AD schema
2023-09-18 18:47:52 Unable to determine the DomainSID, can not enforce uniqueness constraint on local domainSIDs
2023-09-18 18:47:52 
2023-09-18 18:47:52 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:52,281 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1383: Adding DomainDN: DC=my,DC=company
2023-09-18 18:47:52 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:52,313 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1415: Adding configuration container
2023-09-18 18:47:52 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:52,343 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1430: Setting up sam.ldb schema
2023-09-18 18:47:58 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:58,549 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1448: Setting up sam.ldb configuration data
2023-09-18 18:47:59 INFO 2023-09-18 15:47:59,007 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1489: Setting up display specifiers
2023-09-18 18:48:02 INFO 2023-09-18 15:48:02,859 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1497: Modifying display specifiers and extended rights
2023-09-18 18:48:02 INFO 2023-09-18 15:48:02,963 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1504: Adding users container
2023-09-18 18:48:02 INFO 2023-09-18 15:48:02,967 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1510: Modifying users container
2023-09-18 18:48:02 INFO 2023-09-18 15:48:02,970 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1513: Adding computers container
2023-09-18 18:48:02 INFO 2023-09-18 15:48:02,974 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1519: Modifying computers container
2023-09-18 18:48:02 INFO 2023-09-18 15:48:02,978 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1523: Setting up sam.ldb data
2023-09-18 18:48:03 INFO 2023-09-18 15:48:03,238 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1553: Setting up well known security principals
2023-09-18 18:48:03 INFO 2023-09-18 15:48:03,325 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1567: Setting up sam.ldb users and groups
2023-09-18 18:48:03 INFO 2023-09-18 15:48:03,576 pid:18 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1575: Setting up self join
2023-09-18 18:48:04 Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=ms-DFS-Namespace-v2,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=my,DC=company)
2023-09-18 18:48:04 Repack: re-packed 10000 records so far
2023-09-18 18:48:04 Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=group-Display,CN=C0A,CN=DisplaySpecifiers,CN=Configuration,DC=my,DC=company)
2023-09-18 18:48:04 Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=a86fe12a-0f62-4e2a-b271-d27f601f8182,CN=Operations,CN=DomainUpdates,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company)
2023-09-18 18:48:04 set_nt_acl_no_snum: fset_nt_acl returned NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED.
2023-09-18 18:48:04 ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - (3221225506, '{Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights.')
2023-09-18 18:48:04   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 186, in _run
2023-09-18 18:48:04     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
2023-09-18 18:48:04   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 493, in run
2023-09-18 18:48:04     result = provision(self.logger,
2023-09-18 18:48:04   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2325, in provision
2023-09-18 18:48:04     provision_fill(samdb, secrets_ldb, logger, names, paths,
2023-09-18 18:48:04   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1965, in provision_fill
2023-09-18 18:47:48 Set timezone
2023-09-18 18:48:04     setsysvolacl(samdb, paths.netlogon, paths.sysvol, paths.root_uid,
2023-09-18 18:48:04   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1742, in setsysvolacl
2023-09-18 18:48:04     _setntacl(sysvol)
2023-09-18 18:48:04   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1736, in _setntacl
2023-09-18 18:48:04     return setntacl(
2023-09-18 18:48:04   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/ntacls.py", line 228, in setntacl
2023-09-18 18:48:04     smbd.set_nt_acl(
2023-09-18 18:50:30 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:30,949 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2108: Looking up IPv4 addresses
2023-09-18 18:50:30 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:30,950 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2125: Looking up IPv6 addresses
2023-09-18 18:50:30 WARNING 2023-09-18 15:50:30,950 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2132: No IPv6 address will be assigned
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,455 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2278: Setting up secrets.ldb
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,525 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2283: Setting up the registry
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,575 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2286: Setting up the privileges database
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,698 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2289: Setting up idmap db
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,777 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #2296: Setting up SAM db
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,797 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #880: Setting up sam.ldb partitions and settings
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,798 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #892: Setting up sam.ldb rootDSE
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,813 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1305: Pre-loading the Samba 4 and AD schema
2023-09-18 18:50:31 Unable to determine the DomainSID, can not enforce uniqueness constraint on local domainSIDs
2023-09-18 18:50:31 
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,880 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1383: Adding DomainDN: DC=my,DC=company
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,905 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1415: Adding configuration container
2023-09-18 18:50:31 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:31,929 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1430: Setting up sam.ldb schema
2023-09-18 18:50:36 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:36,063 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1448: Setting up sam.ldb configuration data
2023-09-18 18:50:36 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:36,267 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1489: Setting up display specifiers
2023-09-18 18:50:39 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:39,585 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1497: Modifying display specifiers and extended rights
2023-09-18 18:50:39 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:39,651 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1504: Adding users container
2023-09-18 18:50:39 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:39,653 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1510: Modifying users container
2023-09-18 18:50:39 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:39,654 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1513: Adding computers container
2023-09-18 18:50:39 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:39,656 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1519: Modifying computers container
2023-09-18 18:50:39 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:39,658 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1523: Setting up sam.ldb data
2023-09-18 18:50:39 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:39,876 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1553: Setting up well known security principals
2023-09-18 18:50:39 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:39,947 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1567: Setting up sam.ldb users and groups
2023-09-18 18:50:40 INFO 2023-09-18 15:50:40,187 pid:17 /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1575: Setting up self join
2023-09-18 18:50:40 Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=ACS-Identity-Name,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=my,DC=company)
2023-09-18 18:50:40 Repack: re-packed 10000 records so far
2023-09-18 18:50:40 Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=nTDSConnection-Display,CN=41F,CN=DisplaySpecifiers,CN=Configuration,DC=my,DC=company)
2023-09-18 18:50:40 Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=ipsecISAKMPPolicy{7238523D-70FA-11D1-864C-14A300000000},CN=IP Security,CN=System,DC=my,DC=company)
2023-09-18 18:50:41 set_nt_acl_no_snum: fset_nt_acl returned NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED.
2023-09-18 18:50:41 ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - (3221225506, '{Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights.')
2023-09-18 18:50:41   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 186, in _run
2023-09-18 18:50:41     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
2023-09-18 18:50:41   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 493, in run
2023-09-18 18:50:41     result = provision(self.logger,
2023-09-18 18:50:41   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2325, in provision
2023-09-18 18:50:41     provision_fill(samdb, secrets_ldb, logger, names, paths,
2023-09-18 18:50:41   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1965, in provision_fill
2023-09-18 18:50:41     setsysvolacl(samdb, paths.netlogon, paths.sysvol, paths.root_uid,
2023-09-18 18:50:41   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1742, in setsysvolacl
2023-09-18 18:50:41     _setntacl(sysvol)
2023-09-18 18:50:41   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1736, in _setntacl
2023-09-18 18:50:41     return setntacl(
2023-09-18 18:50:41   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/samba/ntacls.py", line 228, in setntacl
2023-09-18 18:50:41     smbd.set_nt_acl(
```

I suppose that the most important part is:

```
ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - (3221225506, '{Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights.')
```

I don't undestand the root cause. Could you please help me with fixing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set_nt_acl_no_snum: fset_nt_acl returned NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED.
ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - (3221225506, '{Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object but has not been granted those access rights.')
```

That suggests some kind of access control settings on the server, possibly due to the configuration of the Samba container itself or the way it interacts with the `TestContainers` environment.

Make sure the Samba configurations are correctly specified. Compare your settings with "[Samba / Setting ACLs / Setting Standard UNIX permissions](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_POSIX_ACLs)"

Check that the volumes `/etc/samba` and `/var/lib/samba` are correctly bound to the respective directories in your container. This is done to maintain the Samba configurations and databases correctly.

The Samba admin password seems to be defined within a file `secrets.yaml`, so make sure the file permissions for `secrets.yaml` allow the docker process to read it. You can check and adjust file permissions using commands like `chmod` and `chown` on UNIX-like systems.

Double-check the  `ADMIN_PASSWORD_SECRET` environment variable is correctly recognized and utilized by your Samba container setup scripts.
And check why you have set the `DOMAIN_ACTION` environment variable twice in your configuration. Ensure that there are no conflicting configurations due to this.

---

In your `docker-compose` file, you have added a capability `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`. However, this is not reflected in your TestContainers setup. Adding capabilities in TestContainers can be done using the [`withCreateContainerCmdModifier` method](https://java.testcontainers.org/features/advanced_options/#customizing-the-container).
For instance:

```java
ldapContainer.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withCapAdd(new Capability[]{Capability.SYS_ADMIN}));
```

---

The mention mentions adding [`.withPrivilegedMode(true)`](https://node.testcontainers.org/features/containers/#with-privileged-mode)

That grants the container elevated privileges, essentially providing the container root privileges on the host system. This allows the container to access various resources and functionalities that are generally restricted and helps in executing processes that require a high level of permissions.

In the context of Samba, a program used for sharing file and print services to SMB/CIFS clients, certain operations carried out during provisioning or normal operations might necessitate elevated privileges to access or modify system files, perform network configurations, or undertake other system-level operations. It is also notable that Samba might interact with various system components such as the system's user and group database, which generally requires higher privileges.

However, running a container in privileged mode has its security implications as it can potentially grant the container access to all devices on the host system. This can expose the system to various security risks, including unauthorized data access and system manipulation.

While enabling privileged mode can resolve issues arising from insufficient permissions, it should be used judiciously and in environments where the security risk is understood and accepted. It is typically recommended for development and testing environments rather than production environments, and when used, it should be accompanied by other security measures to help mitigate potential risks.

Comment: yes, It was my first attempt to try 

```
ldapContainer.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withCapAdd(new Capability[]{Capability.SYS_ADMIN}));

```

but no luck. Problem is solved - please take a look my answer

Comment: @gstackoverflow OK, I have included your answer in mine, with some... caveats ;)

Comment: Actually I am using testContainers for tests only so I think we can accept those risks

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by adding the line:

```
.withPrivilegedMode(true)
```