# How to run docker-compose file using testContainers in spring boot tests?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-boot-test, testcontainers, spring-boot-testcontainers

I have following **docker-compose** file for local development:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  samba:
    image: instantlinux/samba-dc:latest
    hostname: my.org
    environment:
      DOMAIN_ACTION: provision
      REALM: my.org
    volumes:
      - etc:/etc/samba
      - lib:/var/lib/samba
    ports:
      - "389:389"
    secrets:
      - samba-admin-password

volumes:
  etc:
  lib:

secrets:
  samba-admin-password:
    file: secrets.yaml
```

when I run the command `docker-compose up -d` - it starts without any issues and I can work.
In **docker desktop** I see following:

[image]

and container is 100% working and I can connect to **apache directory studio** using port **389**

I want to run this **docker-compose** file in my integration tests (appllication uses **spring boot 3**):

I've added depdendencies:

```
 testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers")
 testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
```

And implemented following base test class:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class IntegrationTestBase {
...
   @Container
   val ldapContainer = DockerComposeContainer(File("C:\\path\\to\\compose\\docker-compose.yml"))
```

When I start empty test that does nothing, only sleeps
I see following in **docker desktop** app:

[image]

The first unexpected thing is port. I expected to see `389:389` as in local **docker-compose** startup.
Another thing - I can't even connect to that container using **apache directory studio**(I tried both: 58875 and 8080 but no luck)

I triefd to fix it by exposing the port:

```
@Container
val ldapContainer = DockerComposeContainer(File("C:\\work\\dsmf\\docker\\docker-compose.yml"))
    .withExposedService("samba", 389)
```

But at this case test doesn't start at all:

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"Cannot link to /azfruytbejv4_samba_1, as it does not belong to the default network"}

    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:247) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.post(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:102) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:31) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:13) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:21) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:35) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.command.StartContainerCmdImpl.exec(StartContainerCmdImpl.java:43) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:441) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:344) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81) ~[duct-tape-1.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:322) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer.startAmbassadorContainers(DockerComposeContainer.java:359) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer.start(DockerComposeContainer.java:190) ~[testcontainers-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testconta inersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:274) ~[junit-jupiter-1.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:261) ~[junit-jupiter-1.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$3(TestcontainersExtension.java:76) ~[junit-jupiter-1.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:89) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:53) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$startContainers$4(TestcontainersExtension.java:76) ~[junit-jupiter-1.18.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.startContainers(TestcontainersExtension.java:76) ~[junit-jupiter-1.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.findTestLifecycleAwareContainers(TestcontainersExtension.java:109) ~[junit-jupiter-1.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.beforeEach(TestcontainersExtension.java:94) ~[junit-jupiter-1.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:165) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:132) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71) ~[na:na]
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69) ~[gradle-worker.jar:na]
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74) ~[gradle-worker.jar:na]

2023-08-10T18:57:45.703+03:00 ERROR 28852 --- [    Test worker] tc.alpine/socat:1.7.4.3-r0               : There are no stdout/stderr logs available for the failed container
```

I am stuck. I have no idea how can I fix it. Waiting for your ideas.

Comment: Context: [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76874083/6309)

Comment: I have included ` .withPrivilegedMode(true)` to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error message you received indicates a network issue, you can try and explicitly define a network in your Docker Compose file and then using it in your Testcontainers configuration.

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  samba:
    image: instantlinux/samba-dc:latest
    hostname: my.org
    environment:
      - DOMAIN_ACTION=provision
      - REALM=my.org
    volumes:
      - etc:/etc/samba
      - lib:/var/lib/samba
    ports:
      - "389:389"
    networks:
      - sambanet

networks:
  sambanet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  etc:
  lib:

secrets:
  samba-admin-password:
    file: secrets.yaml
```

---

Update your Testcontainers configuration to use the network defined in the Docker Compose file.
And, due to the random port assignment by Testcontainers, you need to retrieve the actual mapped port at runtime using the [`getMappedPort()` method](https://java.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#exposing-container-ports-to-the-host).

```java
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class IntegrationTestBase {
    
    @Container
    public static DockerComposeContainer<?> environment = 
        new DockerComposeContainer<>(new File("C:\\path\\to\\compose\\docker-compose.yml"))
            .withExposedService("samba_1", 389, Wait.forListeningPort())
            .withLocalCompose(true);

    @Test
    void someTest() {
        Integer mappedPort = environment.getServicePort("samba_1", 389);
        System.out.println("Mapped port: " + mappedPort);
        // Your test logic here
    }
}
```

Retrieve the mapped port at runtime in your test method using `environment.getServicePort("samba_1", 389)`. You can then use this mapped port to configure your application's connection to the service.

---

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77130089/6309), using [`.withPrivilegedMode(true)`](https://node.testcontainers.org/features/containers/#with-privileged-mode) can help, but has security issues.